# Pixel-perfect android apps

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, pixel-perfect

Is there a tool or app which will optimize building xmls in android app, because right now the only way to check difference between designer's template and an app is making screenshots and using graphical editor for overlaying each over other.

I have some DIY tools, but I am interesting in ready to use products, does somebody know them?

Comment: Please look at [ask] . _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: @JimHawkins Ok, sorry, didn't know that it's a problem. I was just looking for a good software.

Comment: @НазарОвчарчин Have a look at SoftwareRecommendations.StackExchange, You can switch to it in the top left corner and join the community to ask there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you explored the developer options provided with the phones?

- Enable layout bounds to know where a layout ends, its margin and padding
- Profile gpu rendering:onscreen bars, to check UI thread overload.
- Animation speeds: you can increase, decrease and disable animation.

I use this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms_square.android.design.overlay) to check if my UI is aligned properly.

[image]

Comment: oh, thanks, also found several similar apps using tag **overlay**,[app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nazacheres.com.pixelperfect) this allows dynamically change alpha using toolbox which is on top of everything too.